# Preference by user SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, node.js, performance, axapta, dynamic-queries

I have a question about performance on my SQL Server over Axapta ERP.

At this moment we have a multiple queries over ERP, RSS, and others. These queries do not negatively impact the performance, but we have a specific query in web app developed in node.js which does affect our ERP directly. The problem is, the forms in ERP are displaying the data very slowly when other queries (web app) are executing at the same time.

My question: is there are some method to give priority to some queries by user for example? Similar as QOS but for SQL?

I think it is not possible because I never heard anything about it, but one person told me that it is possible.

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Yes, it's call [Resource Governonr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/resource-governor/resource-governor?view=sql-server-2017) A better idea though is to use Extended Events or SQL Server Profiler to find the offending queries and get the web app developers to fix them. Check what those queries do - are they reading entire tables when they only needed a couple of rows? Are they using unindexed fields in `WHERE` statements? Perhaps you could add any missing indexes and improve performance.

Comment: If they *don't* fix them, you can throttle them with Resource Governor, which will slow them down enough that they end up fixing them

Comment: After profiling you may find bad queries that eg apply functions on indexed fields thus making it impossible to use the indexes. Or they may be performing string transformations and comparisons on date/numeric fields to compare them with values instead of the other way around. Perhaps some unfortunate `LIKE '%some search text%` queries to implement "full-text-search" thus scanning an entire table? That's what SQL Server's FTS is for.

Comment: Fixing the perf issue will probably be easier and take less time than configuring Resource Governor. The benefits though would be orders of magnitude better.